# Use NVL on a specified column while still returning all other columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a SQL command that will return all rows and all columns of my records.  However, on 2 of those columns, I want it to use Oracle's NVL, but also in a conditional fashion.  So, using Longitude and Latitude, if one of them is null but the other is not, then set the null value to 0.  So to try to word this better:

Select all columns from MyTable, but set Longitude to 0 if (Longitude is null AND Latitude is not null) and set Latitude to 0 if (Latitude is null AND Longitude is not null)

I don't want to specify the name of every column because there are a decent number of them, so using the concept of * would still probably be ideal.  I also want it to return all records.

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: There is no way to select * and interrupt the *, so you either have to spell out each column or alias long/lat as separate names and select them twice... `Select A.*, case when Latitude is not null and Longitude is null then 0 else longitude end as LongitudeA, case when Latitude is null and Longitude is not null then 0 else latitude end as LatitudeA From table`

Comment: So that sounds like 3 steps then.  1.  Get all columns  2. remove Lat and Long from results 3. Add results of a query for Long and Lat with constraints?

Comment: apparently I missed the actual sql statement when I read that first.  while that has two additional columns, it's closest to what I want.  You should add that as an answer so I can select it as best

Comment: I thought I had.  I guess i navigated away without saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to select * and interrupt the *, so you either have to spell out each column or alias long/lat as separate names and select them twice...

```
SELECT A.*
     , case when Latitude is not null 
             and Longitude is null then 0 else longitude end as LongitudeA
     , case when Latitude is null 
             and Longitude is not null then 0 else latitude end as LatitudeA 
FROM table
```

Now this is oracle so spelling out all the fields from a table would be as easy as...

```
SELECT wm_concat(column_name) 
from All_tab_Cols 
where table_Name = 'TABLE' 
  and Owner = 'SCHEMA' 
  and column_name not in ('LATITUDE','LONGITUDE')
```

Then copy paste the results over the A.* above and no typing required for listing out all the fields (assuming < 4000 characters)

Or, you could use `List_Agg()` if your version of oracle supports it and provide better ordering by column_ID or column_name.

Now given this you could write the SQL to be dynamic SQL but that seems to be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do the with `*` as you modified the selection view. You can do this for the columns you want conditionally modified and select the other columns as such.

```
select
    -- select other columns here
    nvl2(latitude,nvl(longitude, 0), longitude) longitude, 
    nvl2(longitude,nvl(latitude, 0), latitude) latitude
from my_table;
```

If you can do with different column names, you can do something like as @Alvaro did:

```
select
    t.*,
    nvl2(latitude,nvl(longitude, 0), longitude) longitude_new, 
    nvl2(longitude,nvl(latitude, 0), latitude) latitude_new
from my_table t;
```

Comment: that will only return the latitude and longitude columns, though

Comment: @user2869231 yes. You'll have to select other columns manually or use some other column name as Alvaro did

Answer (score 0):

Using `*` in your code is unlikely to save you time in the long term but you can build subqueries like this:

```
SELECT raw_data.*, NVL(foo, 0) as foo_fixed, NVL(bar, 0) AS bar_fixed
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM data
) raw_data;
```

Comment: While this does return all columns still, it 1. creates 2 new columns rather than replaces and 2. converts ALL null values to 0 instead of just the ones who's opposite is not null (so it should only convert Latitude if Longitude is not null, and vice versa)

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed the main point in your question was combining `*` with custom columns, not the usage of `NVL` itself.